# Start Intent in Adapter

Tags: android

I want to start a new activity from this base adapter.

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<ComptePost> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    public  Boolean isActusAstuce;
    public static int flag = 0, counter=0;

    private Context context;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;     
    }

    NVirementEmmeteur main;

    int num = 0;

    ViewHolder holder;
    static String src;

    public EfficientAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<ComptePost> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public EfficientAdapter(NVirementEmmeteur m) {
        main = m;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.toArray().length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView one;
        public TextView two;
        public TextView three;
        public ImageView image;
        public RelativeLayout relative_layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        holder.relative_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context, NVirementEmmeteur.class)); 
            }
        });
        return vi;
    }
}
```

I tried

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NVirementEmmeteur.class));
```

and

```
v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context, NVirementEmmeteur.class));
```

but it force closes my application.

The intent should launch inside an `onclicklistener()` from the list adapter. Can someone tell me how to launch an intent from my efficientadapter.class please.

Here is my logcat output:

> 04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:75)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:2863)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at.adapter.EfficientAdapter$1.onClick(EfficientAdapter.java:141)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   04-11 10:07:50.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11179):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: i post my logcat dude

Comment: please post the activity code i.e creating and setting the adapter

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(activity, NVirementEmmeteur.class));

Comment: @yakusha Where you are inflating your layout?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**you have passed context of activity in constructor so you can also use;**

```
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, NVirementEmmeteur.class));
```

---

check here is sample code you get idea what to do:

setadapter like : `adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, COUNTRIES);`

adapter code:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import com.example.main.util.testActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

class MyArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mcon;
    private String[] COUNTRIES_;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context con, String[] countries) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mcon = con;
        COUNTRIES_ = countries;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return COUNTRIES_.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ListContent holder;
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_spinner_style, null);
            holder = new ListContent();
            holder.line = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.line_);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.name1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.name2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText("" + Html.fromHtml("" + COUNTRIES_[position]));
        holder.name1.setText("" + Html.fromHtml("" + COUNTRIES_[position]));

        holder.line.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mcon.startActivity(new Intent(mcon, testActivity.class));
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}

class ListContent {

    TextView name;
    TextView name1;
    ImageView name2;
    LinearLayout line;

}
```

---

**Edited:**

if your are use this constructor: then `list.setadapter(new EfficientAdapter(myactivity.this));`

```
public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
          this.context = context;     
     }
```

then use : `context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NVirementEmmeteur.class));`

---

if you use this construdtor `list.setadapter(new EfficientAdapter(myactivity.this, ComptePostarray));`

```
public EfficientAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<ComptePost> d) {

        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }
```

then use `activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, NVirementEmmeteur.class));`

**Hope you understud....**

Comment: Are you sure about `getapplicationcontext()`? Dear,its not preferable to use application level context.

Comment: is it possible to call startActivity from an Adapter without context? I dont think so

Comment: can we discuss in chat please ?

Comment: thanks you it work activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, NVirementEmmeteur.class));
 did it :)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for that code, it worked for me. I just wanted to ask where do you usually define onClickListeners(or other methods u then set on buttons etc.) for views in listItem created by recycleAdapter? In the adapter or other class associated with the activity started?

Comment: @VendelínFilip, while using recycle adapter in separate class then onClickListeners will be in fragment or activity.

Comment: @DhavalParmar Ok, I have my custom adapter, activity.java and my custom object type (all separate Java classes). Where should I start to define my onClickListeners? In the adapter as shown here?

Answer (score 9):

I faced this problem previously and tried all of the suggestions above, but the only one helped me to start an activity from an adopter was the solution proposed by @Md. Sajedul Karim.

I modified the code and used like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NesneTani.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 8):

also you can do like, Here `mContext` is Your `BaseAdpter` `Context` Object

```
 Intent ieventreport = new Intent(mContext,Your.class);   
 mContext.startActivity(ieventreport);
```

change your Constructer like, initialise

```
 public EfficientAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ComptePost> d){
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, its same as accepted answer just that, it has more lines, more explanation and this portion missing `public EfficientAdapter(Context context, , ArrayList<ComptePost> d) {
          this.context = context;     
     }`

Answer (score 3):

Replace onClick method with this it may work I didn't tried:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {    
    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), NVirementEmmeteur.class)); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass Context via Constructor and then just use this line of code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
  context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

you can simply get the context from View v or any other created views inside the adapter class using getContext().

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), NVirementEmmeteur.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an intent for the class u need to open.In manifest file .
Eg:

```
<activity android:name=".openingclass"
android:label="@string/app_name">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Then

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Intent i=new Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN");
           StartActivity(i);
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java: Intent in Adapter**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**Accessing Intent Value**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
position = (getIntent().hasExtra("position") && extras != null) ? extras.getInt("position") : 0;
```

**Kotlin: Intent in Adapter**

```
val context = holder.itemView.context

val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("title", holder.button.text.toString())
context.startActivity(intent)
```

**Accessing Intent Value in Kotlin**

```
val letterId = intent?.extras?.getString("letter").toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass activity context from activity and use same context while calling `Intent.`

From activity:

```
yourview.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
```

within adapter:

```
 private Context mContext;


  public EfficientAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;

    }
```

Now use `mContext` to call Intent.

```
startActivity(new Intent(mContext, NVirementEmmeteur.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

set clickListener on listview in mainactivity from there start the intent

```
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity,Test.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Comment: are u getting error or just blank screen?...what is in ur intent activity

Comment: @yakusha, Did you fix the bug? I have the same problem.